# How to write Session_id to a table using Class based view in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I trying to write the session_id stored in the session to a table named 'Picture' using PictureCreateViewClass. I am able to print the session id, which confirms that the session_id is available. I would like to write this value to the Picture table, can someone please suggest how I could do that ?

Below is my views.py

```
class PictureCreateView(CreateView):
    model = picture
    template_name_suffix = '_upload'
    # The below function saves the file to a specified location in model while converting the
    # files to a json format and providing a response

    def form_valid(self, form):
        print self.request.session['s_id']            
        # self.object will contain the object that the view is operating upon.
        self.object = form.save()           
        files = [serialize(self.object)]    
        data = {'files': files}
        response = JSONResponse(data, mimetype=response_mimetype(self.request))
        response['Content-Disposition'] = 'inline; filename=files.json'
        return response

    def form_invalid(self, form):
        data = json.dumps(form.errors)
        return HttpResponse(content=data, status=400, content_type='application/json')
```

models.py

```
class picture(models.Model):
    file = models.ImageField(upload_to=get_upload_file_name)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=50, blank=True)

    #Below line added for storing of session_id
    session_id = models.CharField(max_length =100)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.file.name

    @models.permalink
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return ('upload-new', )

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = self.file.name
        super(picture, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def delete(self, *args, **kwargs):
        """delete -- Remove to leave file."""
        self.file.delete(False)
        super(picture, self).delete(*args, **kwargs)
```

I've tried modifying save method in models.py to the below, but it comes up with an error stating that the 'picture object has no attribute request'

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.session_id = self.request.session['s_id'] # comes up with 'picture object has no attribute request'

    self.slug = self.file.name
    super(picture, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 def form_valid(self, form):         
       # self.object will contain the object that the view is operating upon.
       self.object = form.save(commit=False) 
       self.object.session_id = self.request.session['s_id']    
       self.object.save()
```

Comment: I've placed your code in 'form_valid' method, above `files = [serialize(self.object)]`. When I try to upload the file it comes up with an error 'Bad Request'. Neither the file nor the session_id are written to database. Could it be due to `files = [serialize(self.object)]` ?

Comment: Are you need file content in json response, or url?

Comment: session_id = models.CharField(max_length =100, blank=True, null=True)
; in template - form enctype="multipart/form-data"?;
serialize - can convert to base64 data? (django serializer works only with iterable data)

Comment: I was able to provide a json response before adding this code `self.object = form.save(commit=False) self.object.session_id = self.request.session['s_id']  self.object.save()` in form_valid method.

Comment: I do small prototype - without serialization works fine
[zip archive](http://www.filedropper.com/stack0) 

and print in view - bad practice

Comment: Thank you for the response, I want it to work with serialization, because that sends a response to the front end. This is the [file upload plugin](https://github.com/sigurdga/django-jquery-file-upload), that I am using to upload files.

Comment: Thank you so much..Your code works even with serialize. I missed your suggestion, `session_id = models.CharField(max_length =100, blank=True, null=True)` after implementing this it works!!